# how to use redis stream to spread message to consumer with keys

Tags: asynchronous, redis, stream, key, consumer

lets say we have **3 consumers** *(C1, C2, C3)* listening to a redis stream and we have a **single** consumer group which these 3 consumers belong to.

besides message *unique id* they can also hold a custom **key** value, the same **key** could potentially appear in different messages. the values of **key** item is not known in advanced.

I want to make sure that:

1. once message **M1** hits the stream, it gets picked randomly by **only one** consumer *(not fanning out to all consumers)*
2. however multiple *consumers* **can** consume *messages* with **different** *keys* simultaneously
3. once consumer **C1** gets message **M1** with key **K1** no other consumer can consume other new messages with key **K1**, so basically **C1** can process other related messages with **K1** *(to avoid overring values on processed data)*

```
     STREAM TIMELINE                        CONSUMERS
     T1--------T2--------T3--------T4    /===> [C1]
[ (M1:K1) | (M2:K2) | (M3:K1) | (M4:K3) ] ===> [C2]
                                         \===> [C3]
```

```
CONSUMPTION TIMELINE
T1| @(M1:K1)=>[C1]==================|done|
T2|  @(M2:K2)=>[C2]===|done|
T3|   @       (waiting)             (M3:K1)>[C1]=|done|
T4|    @(M4:K3)=====>[C3]===|done|
```

also process order is not important here, the only important thing here is that not two consumers should process messages with the same id at the same time!

is it possible to achieve the above goals with redis streams (or mabye other means)?

Comment: What is the reason for this dependency? is that to promise M1 will be processed before M3? Or do you really need to make sure the same consumer will processed both?

Comment: the latter, the order is not important here, only thing is that the same consumer should prcoess messages with same key. in kafka you can achive this by giving messages a key, so kafka know which consumer last processed which key and will continue sending the same keys to the same consumer so you are guaranteed that not two consumer process related messages at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this requires some glue because a message's payload is opaque to Redis (i.e. messages have no "key").

The following is a rough back-of-the-napkin idea for a given message M and a key K.

Assume HK is a Redis Hash (e.g. 'consumers_keys'), SK is a Stream ('keys_stream'), and SCn are streams per consumer ('C1'). Also, assume having the following workflows implemented via server-side scripts/functions for atomicity.

Publisher workflow:

1. Check whether K is in HK (`HGET conusmer_keys K1`)
2. If it doesn't exist, publish M to SK (`XADD SK * M`)
3. If it does, the reply is SCn, so publish M to SCn (`XADD SCn * M`)

Consumer workflow:

1. Consume SK as Cn in the consumer group. For each new message:

   1. Set K as SCn in H (`HSET HK K SCn`)
   2. Process M
2. Consume SCn normally

Because the messages are now partitioned between SK and SCn, reclaiming them is more challenging and is left as an exercise to the reader.